# A certain function expansion around x=0 with integral

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

given $f(x)= $$\int_1^x \frac{t^2} {5+t^2} \, dt $ expand the function around $x=0$
What I tried was:

I took $\frac{t^2} {5+t^2}=g(t)$ and then $\frac {1}{t^2}$*$\frac{t^2} {(\frac{5}{t^2}+1)}$ so we get $\frac {1}{(\frac{5}{t^2}+1)}$ after that I took $\frac{5}{t^2}$ and identified it by x, $\frac{5}{t^2}=x$

now it seems kind of better for the geometric expansion ${\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k}$=$\frac {1}{1-x}$

in my case I did $\frac {1}{1-(-x)}$ because I have $\frac {1}{1+x}$ and therefore I got ${\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-x)^k}$=$\frac {1}{1-(-x)}$
after that I return the $\frac{5}{t^2}=x$
and we get  ${\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-\frac{5}{t^2})^k}$=$\frac {1}{(\frac{5}{t^2}+1)}$.

I could not continue from here as I got too lost with it.. the final answer in the book is  ${\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{5^{k+1}(2k+3)}*x^{2k+3}}$ but there is no explanation just a final answer which doesn't help much.

appreciate any help!

Comment: Re you sure that the lower limit for the integral is $1$? because the result that the book gives is af the lower limit was $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you have $$ f'(x) = \frac{x^2}{5+x^2} = \frac{x^2}{5}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{5}} = \frac{x^2}{5}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-x^2}{5}\right)^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+2}}{5^{k+1}}$$
Then you just need to integrate it back
$$ f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t)dt$$
Since $\int_0^x t^{2k+2} = \frac{x^{2k+3}}{2k+3}$ you'll get the result, up to the term $f(0)$, which I believe may be missing in the answer your book is giving.

Comment: Can you please tell me why$ \frac{x^2}{5+x^2} = \frac{x^2}{5}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{5}}$ and not as I did? (my idea came from limits) thank you for the help!

Comment: That's because you can expand $\frac{1}{1-q} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n$ only for $|q|<1$. You need an expansion around $x=0$, that is for small $x$, so you cannot have $q = -\frac{5}{x^2}$ which would be very big.